# Ubuntu 16.04. LTS unable to locate package postgresql-11

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, postgresql

I am running into this issue where I am trying to install postgresql-ll and I followed the instructions given at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt. I have also read previous posts related to this issue and they aren't running into same issue as I am.

When I run `apt-get install` I get the following

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-11 pgadmin4

E: Unable to locate package postgresql-11
E: Unable to locate package pgadmin4
```

I am not sure whether this error means that apt is unable to locate the repository or whether within the repository it is unable to locate the package `postgresql-11`. Since both packages are not being found I am guessing it is unable to find the repository.

However, I have followed repository installation instructions as well as shown below:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg main
```

In the `.list` file I have tried both the URLs:
    http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt
    http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/

Notice the second one has a trailing slash (wasn't sure if that made a difference). Anyone has any debugging suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

After spending 2-3 hours on this problem I realized that I had never run `apt-get update` after adding the `pgdg.list` config file. So indexes of packages available from this repository was not available on my local host. As a result `apt-get install` was unable to find the package.

I will probably not make this mistake again.